# Dimming Before Lock in Low Power Mode

Tags: iphone, ios, screen-lock

The screen sometimes dims before locking to give you a chance to cancel the lock. Sometimes it just locks without warning. How can I get the phone to always dim first before locking?

Answer (score 0):

Go to **Settings** > **Display and Brightness** > **Auto-Lock**, and then select an option other than **Never**. If you set your Auto-Lock to 30 seconds, for example, you should see the screen dim around 20 seconds and turn off completely at 30 seconds.

You can set a longer interval if you want (up to 5 minutes long), but if you want it to be similar to the screen lock/dim on Low-Battery Mode, then a 30-second Auto-Lock is the most similar setting to pick.

Comment: In Low-Battery mode it sometimes dims before locking and sometimes just locks without dimming

Answer (score 0):

This happens in Low Power mode sometimes (often actually) even if you've set Auto-Lock on both iPhone and iPad.

There's currently no fix to this AFAIK but I can propose you to [file a bug report](https://www.apple.com/feedback/iphone/) to Apple.

Answer (score 0):

That *used* to be a setting in iOS 14 and 15, however, it’s seems to have been dropped in iOS 16.  However, it appears, Apple hasn’t updated their documentation.

From the Support Document [Keep the iPhone display on longer](https://support.apple.com/guide/iphone/keep-the-iphone-display-on-longer-iph7117338a8/ios):

> …the Always On Display setting allows a dimmed version of your Lock Screen to stay visible, even when your iPhone is locked…
>
> The display automatically turns off when iPhone is face down or obstructed from view, not near a paired Apple Watch, when a CarPlay session begins, while Continuity Camera is in use, while Low Power Mode is on, while Sleep Focus is on, or at your usual bedtime.
>
> The Always On Display setting is on by default. To turn it off, go to **Settings  → Display & Brightness, then turn off Always On Display.**

At present, the best option is to leave [Apple Feedback](https://www.apple.com/feedback/iphone/) that this feature is documented but non-existant and it should be re-enabled.